# How to query hourly, daily, monthly using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I read https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

But I did not find how to calculate hourly, daily, monthly statistics.
What query parameter should I specify for it?

Guoping

Answer (score 0):

Here you find the API reference guide for Time Dimensions and Metrics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time

You are looking for:
ga:month
ga:date
ga:hour

Comment: Thank you very much!  That is what I am looking for.